# Quickblox, how to get userid from downloaded file with custom object

Tags: android, download, quickblox

i'm developing an android application using quickblox, i use custom object for store one file for every user.
I do a multiple download request, where i download multiple images, all files are downloaded correctly, but i need to know userid for every downloaded file... i try get this information from callback, but i can't get this information on event onComplete for every downloaded file.
There is a way to know user owner?

here is my code:

```
QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBCustomObjectRequestBuilder();
            requestBuilder.setPagesLimit(100);
            requestBuilder.or("idutente", lista);

            QBCustomObjects.getObjects("foto", requestBuilder, new QBCallbackImpl() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Result result) {
                    if (result.isSuccess()) {

                        QBCustomObjectLimitedResult coresult = (QBCustomObjectLimitedResult) result;
                        final ArrayList<QBCustomObject> co = coresult.getCustomObjects();

                        for (int i = 0 ; i < co.size() ; i++) {

                            QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject("foto", String.valueOf(co.get(i).getCustomObjectId()));
                            QBCustomObjectsFiles.downloadFile(qbCustomObject, "immagine", new QBCallbackImpl() {

                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(Result result) {
                                    QBFileDownloadResult downloadResult = (QBFileDownloadResult) result;

                                    if (result.isSuccess()) {
```

> HERE I NEED TO KNOW THE USER ID OF THE FILE DOWNLOADED

```
                                        // extract file
                                        byte[] content = downloadResult.getContent();       // that's downloaded file content
                                        InputStream is = downloadResult.getContentStream(); // that's downloaded file content

                                        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                                        File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/quenchat/");
                                        dir.mkdirs();
                                        File cacheFile = new File(dir, "profilo_"+downloadResult.toString()+".png");

                                        BufferedOutputStream bos;
                                        try {
                                            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFile));
                                            bos.write(content);
                                            bos.flush();
                                            bos.close();
                                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (IOException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }


                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

Thank you

Comment: You can add the user id to the file name and upload the file. When you are done with the download, substring the user id. Simple

Comment: Ok, but how i can get the file name when download is complete? I can get from downloadResult?

Comment: In your OnComplete method, lookout for if it is from download. Then you can access the file name from the result.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to quickblox, how i can get file name from result? i try String filename = result.toString(); but doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **context** for this purpose

Read more about context here http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#Performing_actions_with_context

The right answer will be:

```
QBCustomObject qbCustomObject = new QBCustomObject("foto", String.valueOf(co.get(i).getCustomObjectId()));

String userID = String.valueOf(qbCustomObject.getUserId());

QBCustomObjectsFiles.downloadFile(qbCustomObject, "immagine", new QBCallbackImpl() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Result result, Object context) {
        QBFileDownloadResult downloadResult = (QBFileDownloadResult) result;
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            int userID = Integer.parseInt((String)context);
        }
    }
}, userID);
```

Comment: How to upload and download video content in android using Quickblox?